# Collapsing Toolbar Enter with Scroll Inertia

Tags: android, scroll, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a collapsing toolbar with `scroll|exitUntilCollapsed` set as scroll flags. I like this behaviour overall, however I dislike how it re-expands when I reach the top of the page. If I hit the top and keep scrolling, it expands, which I want, however if I scroll quickly and let the scroll inertia carry it to the top, the toolbar doesn't expand (and the top padding leaves an ugly blank area). I feel like this is how I've seen most apps behave out in the wild, so I'm worried that the answer will be "not possible without some weird hacks", but am I missing something simple to fix this issue?